# get_timeline with rtweet and max. tweet number

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I'm currently using the Standard Twitter API for my bachelor degree. So i wanna analyze the timeline of certain users.
My problem is, that i'm want more than 3200 Tweets with the get_timeline command. So i set up following code in R:

df1 <- get_timeline("user1", n = 3200)

df2 <- get_timeline("user1", n = 3200, max_id= ID of the last tweet from df1)

The first one gives me the intended 3200 Tweets. The second one only provides me 40-50 Tweets. It vaires... but i don't know why? I have seen certain post with the same questions, but the most are a little bit outdated.
So does anyone knows if the twitter API is restricting my request or is my problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user timeline API has a max limit of the most recent 3200 results, so anything beyond that number will not work. The only way you would be able to do this is using the full archive search API to attempt to pull all the Tweets posed by user1.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Actually I have set up the dev environment "Search Tweets: Full Archive/Sandbox" for my app, but I can't pull out more. Can rtweet use this full archive api at all?

Comment: I think the search_fullarchive function may enable that, but I am not sure. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/my-experience-with-twitter-premium-full-archive-api-using-rtweet-f6309f789902) might be worth reading.